# Blazor WASM AD Authentication Hangs with Message "Checking Login State..."

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

This has happened to me a couple of times now, and each time it took me a while to work out what caused it, so I thought I'd document it.

The problem occurs with a Blazor WASM App using MSAL and Azure AD authentication.  If you press login, the message "Checking Login State..." can show and will not open the login popup.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to incorrect entry of the Authority in the appsettings.json file shown following.  If the ClientId is incorrect, an error will be shown during login.  However, if the Authority is incorrect, you just get the unhelpful message "Checking Login State..."

Hopefully this will help someone else out who forgets to set the auth settings, or gets the authority wrong.

[image]